# Showing the index of a row in a bootstrap table

Tags: html, bootstrap-table

I want to be able to display the index of the respective row in a bootstrap table. My table looks like the following:

```
<div class="Explorer" style="display:none">
<table class='table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Points</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
{% for instance in leaderboardDictionaries %}
    {% for category, userDictionary in instance.items %}
        {% if category == "Explorer" %}
            <tr><td> {{category}} </td></tr>
            {% for name, points in userDictionary.items %}
                <tr>
                    <td data-formatter="runningFormatter" data-field="index">HERE I WANT THE INDEX OF THE ROW?!</td>
                    <td>{{name}}</td>
                    <td>{{points}}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
```

I looked in the web and found this but I can't make it work in any useful way....So the suggestion is to make an external function:

```
<script>
function runningFormatter(value, row, index) {
return index+1;
}
</script>
```

Nevertheless how should I use this? The function already takes the row and the index as an argument. And I wonder why there is no 'format-option' for a table, such that i simply displays the row index by default --- or is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `data-` attributes in the `<th>` elements, not the `<td>` elements as they are column-level attributes.

`<th data-formatter="runningFormatter">Rank</th>`

Second, `data-field` is used to map the data from an javascript array or an external source to your columns.  You don't need that since you are writing the table in html.

The `index` will return the row index based on the displayed data.